# Insert Query isn't inserting into the DB

Tags: php, mysql

I am seeing nothing wrong with my script and i don't understand why it will not insert into the database i created. kindly look at my code and advise what could be wrong.
this is the dbcon.php it is used for all Database connections

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$password="";
$db="cottonboard";
$tablename="user";
mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db($db) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

this is now  the script that is to insert the input into the Database,

```
<?php

include "dbcon.php";


extract($_POST);


/* just to test if all fields will be outputted
print_r($_POST);*/ 

$sql="INSERT INTO    $tablename(id,username,password,accesslevel,sex,contactnmuber,employer)
  VALUES('null','$usernameuser','$passworduser','$accesslevel','$gender','$contactnumberuser','$employeruser')" or die(mysql_error());

if($sql)
{
echo"we got here safe";
}

?>
```

Comment: So where are you executing your query? Note: avoid `mysql_` functions, they are deprecated

Comment: You're creating a query in `$sql`, but you never actually execute it.

Comment: By adding 
     mysql_query($sql); the problem is solved. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
// ...
$c = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) or die(mysql_error()); 
// ...
mysql_query($sql, $c);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $tablename(id,username,password,accesslevel,sex,contactnmuber,employer) VALUES('null','$usernameuser','$passworduser','$accesslevel','$gender','$contactnumberuser','$employeruser')";

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db);

if ($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) {
   echo"we got here safe";
}
```

See also: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php